# Simple reminder text pop up on "JSP" page once per session after checking certain condition from java class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, user-interface, struts

I want to add a pop up on my JSP home page, which is simple text pop up with close button on it. 
The pop up I want to open after page load, by checking certain conditions from my java code, if the condition is to show pop up success, it show pop up on page, otherwise no pop up to display.

The reminder pop up box can be closed in 2 places – the “X” in the upper right hand corner or on the “Click here to close this box” text at bottom.

[reminder pop up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnqx1.jpg)
The pop up will be open once per session,if the condition fulfills.

All the style/CSS/border will be added to JSP page. Please suggest.

Comment: The popups are blocked by the browser by default.

Comment: Hi Roman, I want a simple text display to the user after login, to use new service from navigation.

Comment: You should never use popup because popups are blocked by the browser by default.

Comment: I am using simple dialog box on my JSP to display a notification dialog. Now facing issue with the top margin and close button on JSP.
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation